# Change process limit of open file descriptors inside a container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kops

Is there any way to change the limits, open file descriptors in my case, both soft and hard, for a running process inside a pod?

I'm running a memcached deployment using helm `stable/memcached`, but the `1024` open file limit is really short for the intended concurrency.

If it is not possible to do so, what is the right way to change the limits for a deployment or globaly on a kubernetes cluster (running on AWS and setup with `kops`)?

Comment: This is more of the docker image problem than of Kubernetes. http://mtyurt.net/2017/04/06/docker-how-to-increase-number-of-open-files-limit/

Comment: Indeed it is, but it seems one cannot pass `--ulimit` to docker run through a kubernetes deployment.

Comment: It appears that you can't currently set a ulimit but it is an open issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/3595

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `max simultaneous connections` on memcached defaults to 1024, and the chart uses the defaults.

I needed to modify it to pass "-c "